# Need Help Disabling Year/month combobox in mat-calendar Angular Material Component

Tags: angular, angular-material

Good morning. I currently have the following inline mat-calendar angular material component. I don't need this combobox but I do need the arrows. How do I disable it? I've tried several things and nothing is working!

[image]

This is the code Im using at the moment.

```
  <mat-card>
    <mat-calendar
      [(selected)]="selectedDate"
      (selectedChange)="selectedDateChange($event)"
      [minDate]="loadedMinHoliday"
      [maxDate]="loadedMaxHoliday"
      [dateClass]="dateClass()"
      [startAt]="startAt"
    ></mat-calendar>
  </mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `:host ::ng-deep` to access the DOM element for `.mat-calendar-period-button` which is generated by `<mat-calendar>` and overwrite its CSS styling rule.

Note:

> Be sure to include the `:host` selector before `::ng-deep`. If the
> `::ng-deep` combinator is used without the `:host` pseudo-class selector,
> the style can bleed into other components.

**Remark:** *This answer is for hiding the month year button.*

> .component.css

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-calendar-period-button {
  display: none;
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qj3j9j)

---

### References

[(deprecated) /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast answer @Yong Shun, it works perfectly. Though, I noticed it was the only way to reference the current year. Do you know any way to leave the year only? thanks!

Comment: You may refer to [Customizing the parse and display formats](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats). Here is the created [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qflye2?file=src/app/app.component.ts). But doubt there once you display the month button, the button will not be disabled as there is no control/attribute to disable it.